# fail to start graphical interface

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, gui

I'm using Linux Mint 14 and have faced the following problem recently:

after removing and installing some of the software (torchat and LibreOffice to be exact) and rebooting I found myself not being able to log into my system.

first thing I noticed was simply a console line offering to enter my login and password, after that it greeted me with

```
bash: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt: No such file or directory
```

all my attempts to run **startx** resulted in nothing but a black screen with an active mouse arrow

briefly serfing the net I've found that installing **mdm** could be a possible solution, however, after I did that, I've started logging into this very black screen immediately, skipping any time in console

so the only way to get to shell is to drop there using the recovery mode

when I try to launch **startx** there I get the following message

```
Fatal server error: Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

also I can't remove or install anything using this shell due to blocking issues with */var/lib/dpkg/lock*  and being unable to write anything in */var/cache/apt/*

I'd appreciate any suggestions about working this mess out. Thanks in advance